# Menifest.xml - How to Add Multiple Menu type control in Office Menu under Context Menu tag

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, ribbonx

```
Excel Addin is not loading when I add multiple Menu type controls in the Office menu.
```

I'm using  `<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">`

```
    <OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">

    I'm using  `<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">`

    <OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">


    Menifest.xml file has below OfficeMenu config

            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="ContextMenu">
                      <OfficeMenu id="ContextMenuCell">
                         <Control xsi:type="Menu" id="TestMenu">
                            <Label resid="prn.TabLabel" />
                            <Supertip>
                               <Title resid="prn.TabLabel" />
                               <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
                            </Supertip>
                            <Icon>
                               <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                            </Icon>
                            <Items>
                               <Item id="contextitem1">
                                  <Label resid="RightMenu1.TabLabel" />
                                  <Supertip>
                                     <Title resid="RightMenu1.TabLabel" />
                                     <Description resid="RightMenu1.Tooltip" />
                                  </Supertip>
                                  <Icon>
                                     <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                                  </Icon>
                                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                                 <FunctionName>openTaskpaneInPopUp</FunctionName>
                               </Action>
                               </Item>
                            </Items>
                         </Control>
                   
                         <Control xsi:type="Menu" id="TestMenu1">
                            <Label resid="prn.TabLabel" />
                            <Supertip>
                               <Title resid="prn.TabLabel" />
                               <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
                            </Supertip>
                            <Icon>
                               <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                            </Icon>
                            <Items>
                               <Item id="contextitem1">
                                  <Label resid="RightMenu1.TabLabel" />
                                  <Supertip>
                                     <Title resid="RightMenu1.TabLabel" />
                                     <Description resid="RightMenu1.Tooltip" />
                                  </Supertip>
                                  <Icon>
                                     <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                                  </Icon>
                                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                                 <FunctionName>openTaskpaneInPopUp</FunctionName>
                               </Action>
                               </Item>
                            </Items>
                         </Control>
                      </OfficeMenu>
                   </ExtensionPoint>
```

Comment: How does your manifest look like?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that all IDs used in the ribbon XML markup is unique. For example, I see the following the same ID used in both controls:

```
<Item id="contextitem1">
```

By default, if an dd-in attempts to manipulate the Microsoft Office user interface (UI) and fails, no error message is displayed. However, you can configure Microsoft Office applications to display messages for errors that relate to the UI. You can use these messages to help determine why a custom ribbon does not appear, or why a ribbon appears but no controls appear. See [How to: Show Add-in user interface errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-show-add-in-user-interface-errors?view=vs-2022) for more information.

Comment: Eugene,
Thanks for a quick answer.
I'm using  Office Add-ins using Office JS API.

Also found that it is working with single Menu type control( <Control xsi:type="Menu" id="TestMenu">), not for multiple control as shown in the question.

Comment: It doesn't matter what kind of add-ins are used. The Fluent UI is the same for all kind of add-ins.

Comment: Have you tried using unique IDs for controls?

Comment: Yes, I have updated to  <Item id="contextitem2">
Only the first control (<Item id="contextitem1">)is now visible. second control (<Item id="contextitem1">) is still missing

Comment: Do you get any UI errors?

Comment: No Error. It just works on Office 365 online version. in desktop still showing single control